# How to reduce the bitrate loss from video processing via FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

so I use this code to add an intro, outro and watermark to a video but the final result has a loss in bitrate from 2108 bps to 705 bps, how can I keep the bitrate in the 2000 bps range?

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe
-y -i "%%I" -i white.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=hd720,setsar=1[vl];[2:v][2:a][vl][0:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -ar 48000 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

pause
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add `-b:v 2000k`. Or `-crf 20`. The latter is preferable. Don't worry about the bitrate in the latter case

Comment: Excuse me but where exactly do I add it? The process is quite lengthy and I can't do tests.

Comment: Next to `-c:v libx264`